# Generation of exe file in windows forms using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, file-handling

I have developed a console application which reads the values from csv file and updates it in `.c` file in  a specific location. I need to extend it and create an exe file for better GUI. But the same code which works for console application is throwing errors in visual studio 2010 windows forms. Commands like `getline`, `eof()`, `file.open` are throwing errors. I am beginner in coding and any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
     #pragma once
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>  
        #include "stdafx.h"
        namespace Application1

     {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->openFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 82);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 42);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"browse excel file";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // openFileDialog1
            // 
            this->openFileDialog1->FileName = L"openFileDialog1";
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 193);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button2->Text = L"Run";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 150);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
            this->button3->Text = L"browse c file";
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 openFileDialog1->Filter = "Csv Files|*.csv";
                 openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a Csv File";
                  if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
      {

         System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
            System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
       MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadToEnd());
         sr->Close();
      }
             }
              private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                           openFileDialog1->Filter = "C Files|*.c";
                 openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a C File";
                  if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
      {

         System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
            System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
         sr->Close();
      }
                      }
    private: System::Void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

String ^ s1, ^ s2, ^ s3;
String ^ filename, ^ text, ^ line;
String ^ cfilename,^ funcname, ^ signal, ^ value;
String ^ line1, ^ line2;

StreamReader ^ file=gcnew StreamReader(filename);
{
    while(getline(file, cfilename, ',') && getline(file, funcname, ',')
       && getline(file, signal, ',') && getline(file, value, '\n'))
        {

                s1=signal; s2=value;            

                s2 = s2 + ";  //";

                int offset, inset;

                String ^ line;

                StreamWriter ^ cfile=gcnew StreamWriter(cfilename);

                //fstream ^ cfile(cfilename);

                StreamWriter ^ fileOutput=gcnew StreamWriter("output.c");

                //fstream ^ fileOutput;

                fileOutput->open("output.c");

                if(cfile->OpenFile() && fileOutput->OpenFile()) 
                {
                        while(!cfile->eof()) 
                            {                                       
                                if (getline(cfile, line))                               
                                {

                                if((offset = line->find(funcname, 0)) != string::npos)
                                        {

                                        MessageBox::Show("found: " << funcname);    

                                        fileOutput->WriteLine(line);

                                    while(getline(cfile,line1))
                                            {

                                            if((inset=line1.find(s1, 0)) !=string::npos)
                                                {

                                                MessageBox::Show("found: " << s1);

                                                string ^ s3 = s1+ "=" +s2;

                                                MessageBox::Show(s3);

                                                line1->replace( inset, inset+s1.size(), s3 );

                                                }       
                                            fileOutput->Writeline(line1);
                                            }                                   
                                        }

                                fileOutput->Writeline(line);

                                    }
                                }
                            }                       
                        cfile->close();

                        fileOutput->close();

                        cfile->open(cfilename);

                        fileOutput->open("output.c");

                        if(cfile.is_open() && fileOutput.is_open())
                            while(getline(fileOutput,line2))
                                cfile->Writeline(line2);
                        cfile->close();
                        fileOutput->close();
                        }

                    }
        file->close();
        remove("output.c");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

}
;}
}
```

My working C++ console application code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s1, s2, s3;
string filename, text, line;
string cfilename,funcname, signal, value;
string line1,line2;


cout << "Enter excel filename" << endl;
cin >> filename;

fstream file(filename);

if (!file) {
           cerr << "No such file exists or the file is open." << endl;
           exit(1);
            }
if(file.is_open())
{
    while(getline(file, cfilename, ',') && getline(file, funcname, ',')
       && getline(file, signal, ',') && getline(file, value, '\n'))
        {
        cout << cfilename << '\t' << funcname << '\t' << signal << '\t' << value << '\n';

        string s1=signal,s2=value;          

                s2 = s2 + ";  //";

                int offset, inset;

                string line;

                fstream cfile(cfilename);

                fstream fileOutput;

                fileOutput.open("output.c");

                if(cfile.is_open() && fileOutput.is_open()) 
                {
                        while(!cfile.eof()) 
                            {                                       
                                if (getline(cfile, line))
                                {

                                if((offset = line.find(funcname, 0)) != string::npos)
                                        {

                                        cout << "found: " << funcname << endl;  

                                        fileOutput << line << '\n';

                                    while(getline(cfile,line1))
                                            {

                                            if((inset=line1.find(s1, 0)) !=string::npos )
                                                {
                                                cout<<"found: " << s1 << endl;

                                                string s3 = s1+ "=" +s2;

                                                cout<<s3<<'\n';

                                                line1.replace( inset, inset+s1.size(), s3 );

                                                }       
                                            fileOutput << line1 << '\n';
                                            }                                   
                                        }

                                fileOutput << line << '\n';

                                    }
                                }
                            }                       
                        cfile.close();

                        fileOutput.close();

                        cfile.open(cfilename);

                        fileOutput.open("output.c");

                        if(cfile.is_open() && fileOutput.is_open())
                            while(getline(fileOutput,line2))
                                cfile<<line2<<'\n';
                        cfile.close();
                        fileOutput.close();
                        }

                    }
        file.close();
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

[image: These are the errors i am facing.]

Comment: The reason why you are not able to compile it is, that you are mixing native c++ code from the Standard Library with managed C++ CLI code from the .Net framework. Use one or another, and it will work.

Comment: could u please elaborate... Can i make the native c++ code to work in windows forms by adding some library or doing minor modifications?

Comment: You should Show the Compiler Errors here in the question so that People can help easier.

Answer (score 2):

C++ CLI project what you are using is able to compile native c++ code and also managed c++ code. Your code doesn't compile just because you try to call e.g. `std::getline(System::String^, ...)`, what is calling native c++ function with managed c++ parameter. It is possible to use `std::getline`, but you have to use `std::string` instead. I have changed your code, that way you will be able to compile it. I have removed `StreamReader` because then you won't need to mess with opening closing the files.

Form1.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Application1
{
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1();

    protected:
        ~Form1();

    private: System::Void Run(System::String^ FileName, System::String^ OutputFileName);
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::ComponentModel::Container^ components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->openFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 82);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 42);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"browse excel file";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // openFileDialog1
        // 
        this->openFileDialog1->FileName = L"openFileDialog1";
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 193);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->button2->Text = L"Run";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 150);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button3->Text = L"browse c file";
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button3_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
    }
#pragma endregion  
    };
}
```

Form1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"        

namespace Application1
{
    Form1::Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    Form1::~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
            delete components;
    }


    System::Void Form1::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "Csv Files|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a Csv File";

        if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {           
            System::String^ FileName = openFileDialog1->FileName;
            System::String^ FileContent = System::IO::File::ReadAllText(FileName);
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(FileContent);
        }
    }


    System::Void Form1::button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "Csv Files|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a Csv File";

        if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {           
            Run(openFileDialog1->FileName, "Output.txt");
        }
    }


    System::Void Form1::button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        openFileDialog1->Filter = "C Files|*.c";
        openFileDialog1->Title = "Select a C File";

        if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }


    System::Void Form1::Run(System::String^ FileName, System::String^ OutputFileName)
    {
        if (!System::IO::File::Exists(FileName))
        {
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("File '" + FileName + "' doesn't exists");
            return;
        }

        array<System::String^>^ InputLines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(FileName);
        System::Collections::Generic::List<System::String^>^ OutputLines = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::String^>();

        // do your procesing here
        for (int i=0; i<InputLines->Length; i++)
        {
            System::String^ OutputLine = "";

            // sample code
            if (InputLines[i]->Contains("abc"))
                OutputLine += InputLines[i] + "test";

            OutputLines->Add(OutputLine);
        }

        // save output
        System::IO::File::WriteAllLines(OutputFileName, OutputLines);
    }
}
```

Btw, you definitely have to work on your coding style :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. You have added 2 buttons for browsing csv files. But i had problem in adding the 3rd button, which is Run where my c++ code should run. The commands in my c++ code are the ones which are giving problem. I also tried by adding 'std::string' in my existing code but it gives an error as string is not a member of std.

Comment: "string is not a member of std"  is because the compiler does not know about the std::string ...you have to add #include <string> into your cpp file

Comment: I have added the #include <string>, but still no use. Please tell me where and how to include my c++ code in your above suggested code. I tried including in the 3rd button but it went to some 60 odd errors.

Comment: you can't just put it there, because in your c++ example you are trying to read values from the console through getline ...but you can't use this function in GUI, because the console is not available. What you need to do is to modify your c++ code that way that it will be possible to start it without console.

Comment: Can u plz tel me how to use getline command to read the values in the csv file and assign it to the strings? Stuck up der.